# Error al ejecutar el composer : JIT compilation failed: no more memory in phar:

Tags: php, laravel, php7, composer

Al ejecutar composer, recibo el siguiente error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught ErrorException: preg_match_all(): JIT
>   compilation failed: no more memory in phar:

Answer (score 2):

En mi caso el error se debia a mi version de PHP 7.3 la cual tiene un bug, se resolvio cambiando el siguiente valor en el php.ini:

vi /usr/local/etc/php/7.3/php.ini 
deshabilitar el  PHP PCRE JIT cambiando los siguientes valores:

;pcre.jit=1
to
pcre.jit=0